# how to attach javadoc in project

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc

i have created an javadoc for my app using "generate javadoc" option and created a jar file of my project. now when i add this jar to other project i have also added javadoc for that jar throght project properties ( ie.Project -> Properties - > Java Build Path -> my.jar expand jar file click the ‘>’ arrow next to the library name to expand the library reference and  used the edit buttons to set the the Javadoc location)
still when i hover methods javadoc pane says

*This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.*

so can anyone tell me what are the step to add javadoc or m i mission somthing????

Comment: This might help: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/7143635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay  i have found an answer by myself to add method info with method we have to check

```
 export java files and resources.
```

option while generating jar file